# Form fields created using iText5 PDF Java library, duplicates the fields when uploaded to Adobe sign tool

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, adobe, form-fields

[Downloaded pdf with form field from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOhkT.jpg)

[Adobe sign tool duplicating the form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDZFu.jpg)

I have tried creating date fields and signature fields for PDF using iText5 Library and generated the PDF. In the downloaded pdf when opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader, I see only one field created, but when the pdf is uploaded to Adobe Sign, the form fields are duplicated.

Below is my code:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,40,40,60,50);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,baos);

PdfPTable signatureTable = createPdfTable(2);
signatureTable.setWidths(new int[] {1,1});
PdfPCell signatureCell = new PdfPCell();

TextField signatureText = new TextField(writer,signatureCell,"TCSig1_es_:signer1:signature");
signatureText.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);

PdfFormField signField = signatureText.getTextField();
signField.setPlaceInPage(4);
FieldPositioningEvents signatureEvent = new FieldPositioningEvents(writer, signField);
signatureCell.setCellEvent(signatureEvent);
signatureTable.addCell(signatureCell);

document.add(signatureTable);
```

Comment: Are you able to share an example PDF? And what happens if you fill them out? Are the values also duplicated or can you fill each field individually? This would be the case if e.g. the fields are in the annots array twice...But many other reasons possible. We know for sure when we see the PDF...

Comment: Considering your edit: @Lonzak asked to share a **PDF**, not a literal screen shot.

Comment: Hi @Lonzak Thanks for your response. I have attached the images in the issue description.  With the above code, when pdf is generated its only a single form field as shown in (Downloaded pdf with form field from code) that accepts keying in values but when the same pdf is uploaded to Adobe Sign Tool, the fields are duplicated as shown in (Adobe sign tool duplicating the form fields)